# SQL Server : exclude rows with NULL values after CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, max, case, min

The query below aggregates data from a logging table in the way I want...

```
SELECT 
    [TransactionNumber]
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'start' 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated Status to: Delivered to Web' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'end' 
    FROM [ILLData].[dbo].[History]
    GROUP BY [TransactionNumber] 
    /*
    227882  2015-09-29 14:17:07.443 2015-09-29 15:27:03.180
    227883  NULL    NULL
    227884  2015-09-29 14:29:22.340 NULL
    227885  NULL    2015-09-29 14:59:54.677
    */
```

...but I want to exclude any of the resulting rows containing NULL values. I tried the queries below, but I keep getting the same results and the rows with NULL values are not excluded.

```
SELECT 
    [TransactionNumber]
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'start' 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated Status to: Delivered to Web' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'end' 
FROM 
    [ILLData].[dbo].[History]
WHERE 
    'start' IS NOT NULL 
    AND 'end' IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    [TransactionNumber] 

/* still get rows with NULL values */

SELECT 
    [TransactionNumber]
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'start' 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated Status to: Delivered to Web' THEN  [DateTime] END) AS 'end' 
FROM 
    [ILLData].[dbo].[History] 
GROUP BY  
    [TransactionNumber] 
HAVING 
    'start' IS NOT NULL 
    AND 'end' IS NOT NULL

/* still get rows with NULL values */

WITH history AS 
(
   SELECT  
       [TransactionNumber]
       ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'start' 
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated Status to: Delivered to Web' THEN [DateTime] END) AS 'end' 
   FROM 
       [ILLData].[dbo].[History]
   GROUP BY 
       [TransactionNumber])
SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE 'start' IS NOT NULL 
  AND 'end' IS NOT NULL 

/* still get rows with NULL values */
```

Is there a way to filter the results of my query which used `CASE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your field's names because 'start' will never be null because SQL compare text value with null. Little change and your query will be fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 
[TransactionNumber]
,MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) AS [start] 
,MAX(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated Status to: Delivered to Web' THEN [DateTime] END) AS [end] 
FROM [ILLData].[dbo].[History]
GROUP BY [TransactionNumber]) x
WHERE [start] IS NOT NULL 
AND [end] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Rafal, when I try this I get an error: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'start'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'end'.`

Comment: Now it should be good. I forgoted that "Having" is executed before "SELECT".

Comment: Dziękuję !!! it works. So it looks like the query needed to be nested. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Nie ma za co :)
If you want to use aliases it should be nested but you can use having with MIN(CASE WHEN [Entry] = 'Updated status to Awaiting OCLC Sending' THEN [DateTime] END) IS NOT NULL